# Scatter plot over 2D-histogram in matplotlib with log-scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, scatter-plot

I have two sets of points with values (x, y). One is enormous (300k) and one is small (2k). I want to show a scatter plot of the latter over a 2D-histogram of the former in log-log scale. `plt.xscale('log')`-like commands keep messing up the histogram and when I just take logs of x's and y's and then do all the plotting, my ticks are say -3 not 10^-3 and the pretty logarithmic minor ticks are missing altogether. What's the most elegant solution in matplotlib? Do I have to dig into the artist layer?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have done so far, including toy dataset. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forgive a bit of self-advertisement, you may use my library `physt` (see https://github.com/janpipek/physt). Then, you can write code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from physt import h2

# Data
r1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000)
r2 = np.random.normal(0, .3, 20000) + r1
x = np.exp(r1)
y = np.exp(r2)

# Plot scatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x[:1000], y[:1000], s=2)

H = h2(x, y, "exponential")
H.plot(ax=ax, zorder=-1)   # Necessary to put behind
```

Which, I hope is the solution to your problem:

[image: physt-produced histogram+scatter]

Comment: Could this be possible in 3D?

Comment: Not sure. Physt does not provide such feature but some other library may.